# Xamarin Forms - iOS CLLocationCoordinate2D is not initializing correctly

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, location

I'm trying to initialize a [CLLocationCoordinate2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corelocation.cllocationcoordinate2d?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) class in a iOS custom render that i have, and in the constructor i can pass a **Latitude** and **Longitude** (double, double) as parameters to initialize it, but whatever the values i give, the class always comes with the default double value for the Latitude and Longitude. *(0,0)*, here is how i tried to initialize it at first:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D iosCoords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(38.00000000000000, -9.00000000000000);
//This inits has (0,0)
//Note: the double has 14 numbers in the decimal part
```

also tried:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D iosCoords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D();
iosCoords.Latitude = 38.00000000000000;
iosCoords.Longitude = -9.00000000000000;
//Still (0,0)
```

And then i thought it might have to do with the number of decimals i have, so i simplify and the weirdest thing happened:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D iosCoords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D();
iosCoords.Latitude = 38;
iosCoords.Longitude = -9;
//it gives (0,-9)
```

Can someone point out what i'm doing wrong or how should i do this? this is pretty standart so i don't know what is causing this or what i'm even doing wrong. i'm using a real device for testing, and a real mac for hosting, here is a screenshot of the last code:

[image]

Note: i deleted the app several times, also deleted the *bin* and *obj* folders from the project folders and did the clean and rebuild on the solution too, and i'm 90% sure that it's not just a debugger problem, because the coords are going to be reflected into a map, and it's showing the location at the (0,0).

**Edit**: After some testing, i found out that the OnElementPropertyChanged was being called twice for the same property almost at the same time, the property is an non nullable boolean, so i don't know how it enter the method when the value was already the same (default value, false), so i just did a check when the property was only true, and it stopped doing this. but i still dont understand how the last part of my question happened.

Comment: I just gave it a shot and it worked fine for me. Can you do System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(iosCoords); and see what it prints? This looks like a debugger problem, especially if you are using VS for Windows.

Comment: @AndresCastro i think i found the problem and the solution, this code was inside the OnElementPropertyChanged, when my property changed, it initialized this class, the bizzare thing is that the OnElementPropertyChanged was being fired twice, on android it only fires once, but on iOS (the property is a bool), it fires even when the property new value has the same has the old value, so i just did a check for when the property is true, and the class initializes correctly now. if you could clarify why this happens, and why (even tho it's called twice at the same time), it doesn't initialize

Comment: i haven't post a solution yet because i don't know why this happens, even tho i found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the OnElementPropertyChanged was being called twice for the same property almost at the same time, and it seems that in iOS even if the property starts with the default value, it always passes first on the PropertyChanged, i just needed to prevent multiple calls on the same event and it fixed my problem, i hope someone can give a better anwser than this