# Xamarin.Forms iOS Picker jumping to last item after closing dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I just encountered this issue on a project i am working on, and am stumped. As you can see in the gif below, when selecting an item with the Picker dialog on iOS (Emulator), the selected value jumps to the last item in the list after confirming (no matter if I tap out of the dialog or use the Done button). On Android the corresponding dialog behaves properly. **I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.356 and Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.1 for this**.

[Minimum Bug replica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Ad4.gif)

```
    public class PickerItemModel
    {
        public string TestProp { get; set; }

        public PickerItemModel(string t) => TestProp = t;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return TestProp;
        }
    }

public class MainViewModel : ComputedBindableBase
{

    public List<PickerItemModel> PickerItemModels { get; set; } = new List<PickerItemModel> {
            new PickerItemModel("Hello"),
            new PickerItemModel("Stackoverflow")
        };

        public PickerItemModel SelectedModel { get; set; }
```

The ComputedBindableBase does implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged Event and automatically raise it when a property is changed.

```
        <Picker Title="Test"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemModels}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}" />
```

The question is now, either how do i fix this behavior, or what is valid workaround for it. I am willing to use some custom packages for this, but I cannot implement the complete dialog on my own as I have some restrictions on the project in terms of time spent on it.

Thank you in advance for your time. :-)

**EDIT:**

I recompiled the code now after a few hours and it works now. I assume it was some bug with old code not being properly redeployed or something... I am also using VS on Mac so that may also just be the cause since it has behaved buggy since day one...

Also, here is the BindableBase class (ComputedBindableBase does nothing but add an utility function):

```
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void Set<T>(ref T target, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            target = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does ComputedBindableBase do?

Comment: does this happen when you have more than 2? for example 10, and if you click Item2, Item1, and then "Done", does it  jump to the last item? just trying to remove some bug options here

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais The issue in the original project appears with multiple items, not just two. But for some reason, i now can compile the project without any additional changes...
Also, the BindableBase class only contains
`
       protected void Set<T>(ref T target, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            target = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
`
as a definition

Comment: i think it's just a "bug", developing using Mac has the build host causes some issues when eveything is not done correctly, cancel the building, remove the cable while the vs is in debug, no clean | remove bin/obj for a while, i had an similiar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57857888/8182493 where iOS was firing events twice when it shouldn't, a clean/rebuild resolved my issue (after a long time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not repro this issue using Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.356 and Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.1. My code is functionally the same as yours with the one exception that I did not derive my viewmodel from ComputedBindableBase. The following code works as expected

**View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:app2="clr-namespace:App3"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app2:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Picker Title="Please select..."
                ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemModels}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class PickerItemModel
{
    public string TestProp { get; set; }
    public PickerItemModel(string t) => TestProp = t;
    public override string ToString() => TestProp;
}

public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public List<PickerItemModel> PickerItemModels { get; set; } = new List<PickerItemModel> {
        new PickerItemModel("Hello"),
        new PickerItemModel("Stackoverflow")
    };
    public PickerItemModel SelectedModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I retried using the code without the computedBindableBase class (was an old version of something i used when i practised in that Test Project). That worked. So I will wait for a bit if someone has a better idea what the reason could be, otherwise I will just accept this answer.

Comment: I have the suspicion that this is the only answer this question will get. Could you please mark it as the correct answer if it solved your problem?